# Why these two cases are true in the same time!

Tags: real-analysis, limits, inequality

I have an inequality of the form:

$$a<1/f(k).......(*)$$

where $f(k)>0$ for all $k$ and goes to infinity with $k$ and $a$ is a positive real numbers

and I have two statements:

(1) There is no real number $a>0$ if $(*)$ is verified for all $k>m$  where $m$ is positive integer. This case is true.

(2) There is still real numbers $a>0$ if $(*)$ is verified for **infinitely many indices** (but not all) $k>m$  where $m$ is positive integer. This case is true.

My **question** is: Why these two cases are true in the same time!

Comment: I have some doubts about $(2)$. Do you happen to have an example ?

Comment: @Peter: No, I come across with these two cases when working on other problem.

Comment: $(1)$ is clearly true because $1/f(k)$ is obviously a null-sequence.

Comment: @Peter: For example: Take $f(k)=p_{k}$ where $p_{k}$ is the sequence of primes and use broncoAbierto answer.

Comment: I cannot follow. If I fix some $a>0$, then $1/f(k)>a$ must hold for this $a$ and infinite many $k$. This is surely not the case , if you choose $f(k)=p_k$.

Comment: @Peter: Yes, unfortunately the answer below is wrong.

Comment: What is the domain of $f$? I was assuming the positive reals, based on " and  is a positive real numbers".

Comment: @broncoAbierto: It is positive integers.

Comment: Ok, that changes everything. Can (2) be true then?

Comment: @broncoAbierto: In this case, no, by the above comments. Thanks.

Comment: @broncoAbierto: Maybe this is true if we assume that $a$ depend also on the indice $k$.

Comment: @Helena But then it still wouldn't be satisfied for a particular constant.

Comment: @broncoAbierto: Yes. it is the case.

Comment: Since $1/f(k)$ is a null-sequence, for every $a>0$ from some index $k$ on we must have $1/f(k)<a$ , so we can have the condition $1/f(k)>a$ only finite many times. This shows that $(2)$ must be false.